# The installer information on the recovery server is damaged

Tags: macbook-pro

I keep getting the error shown in the title when trying to re-install macOS, one thing that I did was acidentally delete my macintosh HD partition and this started happening. I tried to fix the date via online youtube videos but that did not seem to work. What can I do to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Internet Recovery Mode ⌘ + ⌥ + R rather than plain old Recovery Mode ⌘ + R?

Comment: Try: Open Terminal (menubar > Utilities > Terminal) and enter `ntpdate -u time.apple.com` and repeat installing High SIerra.

Comment: @nohillside: Can any question be a duplicate of a question asked in the future?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes :-) Usually I would say "if the answers there are better". In this case it's rather "if there is a higher chance that the OP comes back and adds details".

Comment: @nohillside: OK. In the other (duplicate) question, you posted a comment with a link to this question. Will all users be able to view this question or just the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege?

Comment: @DavidAnderson The links are visible to everybody. Honestly, without further details the question will remain unanswearable (could be something as simple as the Mac not connected to the Internet).