# "The Installer information on the recovery server is damaged" when installing macOS Sierra

Tags: macos

Im trying to reinstall macOs Sierra but get

[image]

In the log I only get

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where did you download macOS Sierra from and on which Mac model are you trying to install it?

Comment: Also, the problem has come up before (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381111/the-installer-information-on-the-recovery-server-is-damaged). There are no answers, but did you try the recommendations in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the Mac and keep holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and you will get the Internet Recovery screen. Connect to WiFi or via Ethernet and you will be to reinstall the OS.

A couple things to watch on machines that have been off for a while:

- check the date and time, if they are not within 4 minutes of reality, the check for valid software can fail.
- Be very clear if your macOS installer was downloaded a while back, the signing certifications can be expired.
- Be aware that even an unexpired certificate can fail to install if there are errors in the network or disk.

Comment: Sounds like the Certs are just no longer valid, so none of these suggestions are going to work